# When I click on submit button no function is called

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest

in my website when I click a submit button it should show all the links in a textbox ,but my submit button is not working, noting happens when I click it. Here's my code. My submit button has onclient click property.

```
        protected void btnRender_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string strResult = string.Empty;

            WebResponse objResponse;
            WebRequest objRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(url.Text);

            objResponse = objRequest.GetResponse();

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                strResult = sr.ReadToEnd();
                sr.Close();
            }
            strResult = strResult.Replace("<form id='form1' method='post' action=''>", "");
            strResult = strResult.Replace("</form>", "");
            //strResult = strResult.Replace("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" /><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">");
            div.InnerHtml = strResult;

        }

        protected void btn_createlink_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var links = TextBox1.Text.Split(new string[] { "\n", "\r" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            foreach (var link in links)
            {
                if (!IsLinkWorking(link))
                {
                    //Here you can show the error. You don't specify how you want to show it.
                    TextBox2.Text += string.Format("{0}\nNot working\n\n ", link);
                }
                else
                {
                    TextBox2.Text += string.Format("{0}\n working\n\n", link);
                }
            }
        }


        bool IsLinkWorking(string url)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);

            //You can set some parameters in the "request" object...
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, cert, chain, ssl) => true;

            try
            {
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                //TODO: Check for the right exception here
                return false;
            }
        }


        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox1.Text = "";
            TextBox2.Text = "";
            url.Text = "";
        }

    }
```

here is my client side code
here  i have function called finda() .when client clicks on submit button it should call but this not happening

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server"> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function finda() {
            var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
            var b = document.getElementById("TextBox1");
            b.value = "";


            for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                a[i] = a.length.value;


                if (a[i] == null) {
                    alert("Their is no links");
                }
                else {
                    b.value = b.value + "\r\n\n" + a[i];
                }

            }

            //            window.open("http://www.fillsim.com");
            window.close();
            //   window.open("WebForm3.aspx?req=" + b.value);


        }
    </script>
   <script type = "text/javascript">
       var defaultText = "http://www.example.com";
       function waterMarkText(txt, evt) {
           if (txt.value.length == 0 && evt.type == "blur") {
               txt.style.color = "red";
               txt.value = defaultText;
           }
           if (txt.value == defaultText && evt.type == "focus") {
               txt.style.color = "green";
               txt.value = "";
           }
       }
</script>
</asp:Content> 

 <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
 <form id="form1"  >
    Enter the URL:<br />
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="url" runat="server" Width="263px"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnRender" runat="server" Text="Page Render" OnClick="btnRender_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="btn_submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="javascript:finda();" />
    <asp:Button ID="btn_createlink" runat="server"
        Text="Create link" OnClick="btn_createlink_Click" />
```

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Height="371px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="409px"></asp:TextBox>
<div class="ab" id="div" runat="server">


    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Clear" 
        Width="71px" />


</div>
</form>
```

Comment: It's looks as though there are code missing? A div tag and 2 textboxes? Can you add it?

Comment: @JLC007 edited just go through

Comment: Did you check adding breakpoint and see if it hits Button1_Click event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `form` tag should have `runat="server"` attribute so that ASP.NET postback events can be properly handled.

Comment: @Knagis then this error will occur " A page can have only one server-side Form tag. "

Comment: Why do you need the inner form tag? ASP.NET WebForms is intended to be used with just one tag.

Comment: for this reason                                                          strResult = strResult.Replace("<form id='form1' method='post' action=''>", "");
            strResult = strResult.Replace("</form>", "");

Comment: or any other method to post the method